# How do I solve trigonometrical simultaneous equations?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

(Note: this question has elements of physics in it but I am looking for a solution to the purely mathematical side of it.)

In trying to work out the resultant velocity and angle of an elastic collision, I have come across a pair of trigonometric simultaneous equations.

$$ m_1\cdot v_1 + m_2\cdot v_2 \cos \theta_i = (m_1 + m_2) v_f \cdot \cos \theta_f $$
$$ m_2\cdot v_2 \sin \theta_i = (m_1 + m_2) v_f \cdot \sin \theta_f $$

In these, there are two colliding bodies, 1 and 2, of which each has a mass $m_n$ and a velocity $v_n$. $\theta_i$ is the angle of incidence, $\theta_f$ the final angle, and $v_f$ the final total velocity.

Now, I can solve this partially: I can rearrange an equation for $v_f$, substitute it into the other, and come out with another equation:

$$ v_f = \frac{m_1\cdot m_2 + m_2\cdot v_2 \cos \theta_i}{(m_1 + m_2) \cos \theta_f} $$
$$ \theta_f = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{m_2\cdot v_2 \sin \theta_i}{(m_1 + m_2) \frac{m_1\cdot m_2 + m_2\cdot v_2 \cos \theta_i}{(m_1 + m_2) \cos \theta_f}}\right) $$

Convoluted. Normally, this would not be too much of a problem, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to rearrange this so that

- All $\theta_f$ terms are on the left; and
- All $\theta_f$ terms combine to *one* term - i.e. no extra trigonometrical functions

How is it done?

Answer (score 3):

If you multiply the 
first equation by
$\sin \theta_i$
and the second equation by
$\cos \theta_i$
and then subtract them,
the terms on the left
with $\theta_i$
will cancel out
leaving a term with
$\sin \theta_i$
and the terms on the right
will have
$\cos \theta_f \sin \theta_i
-\sin \theta_f \cos \theta_i
=\sin(\theta_i-\theta_f)
$.

You then have
$a \sin \theta_i
=b \sin(\theta_i-\theta_f)
$
for certain $a$ and $b$.

With this,
you can get
$\theta_f$
in terms of
$\theta_i$
and the other parameters.

Comment: What does that multiplication get you? I can do the basic multiplication but I don't see where you got your terms from.

Comment: Interestingly, if one squares both of the above equations listed in the question and then adding, one can easily solve for $\theta_i$.

Comment: Make that an answer.